# Date validation in Cake

Tags: validation, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

How can I get the built-in date formatting working in my Cake app? Maybe I am making some simple mistake. I'm focused on the model code right now, I think this is what I am screwing up.

On the page it looks like it's working, showing three select widgets with months, days, years in that order. However, when I submit the form I'm getting the "Must be a valid date" message.

Here's the view code I have:

```
echo $this->Form->create('Subscription');
echo $this->Form->input('starts',array('type'=>'date','dateFormat'=>'MDY'));
echo $this->Form->end('Submit', true);
```

And in my model the validation looks like this:

```
'starts' => array(
    'date' => array(
    'rule' => array('date', array('MDY')),
    'message' => 'Must be a valid date',
    ),
    'notempty' => array(
        'rule' => array('notempty'),
        'message' => 'Start date is required',
    ),
),
```

The field I'm trying to update is declared as DATETIME in the mysql db, in case that makes a difference.

Comment: i see now that in my Validation::date() call the "date" coming in includes the time, and i don't think it will accept the time.

Comment: Isn't the `NOT_EMPTY` rule a constant? Or is that old school now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't remember off the top of my head, but I think you have to use the generated date inputs to construct your own date.

!!- Scrub that -!!

```
‘Mdy’ e.g. December 27, 2006 or Dec 27, 2006 (comma is optional)
```

If no keys are supplied, the default key that will be used is ‘ymd’.

I'm with SpawnCxy on this.

Comment: ok i might give that a try. one thing i noticed is the date is being updated correctly if i don't validate it, which makes me think that you wouldn't need to build-up the date string yourself. 

plus that seems like more work than you'd have to do. cake is so nice like that.

Answer (score 1):

I found the following information in the Cake 2.0 data validation documentation ([http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html#Validation::datetime](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html#Validation%3a%3adatetime)):

```
Validation::datetime(array $check, mixed $dateFormat = 'ymd', string $regex = null)
This rule ensures that the data is a valid datetime format. A parameter (which can be an array) can be passed to specify the format of the date. The value of the parameter can be one or more of the following:

'dmy' e.g. 27-12-2006 or 27-12-06 (separators can be a space, period, dash, forward slash)
'mdy' e.g. 12-27-2006 or 12-27-06 (separators can be a space, period, dash, forward slash)
'ymd' e.g. 2006-12-27 or 06-12-27 (separators can be a space, period, dash, forward slash)
'dMy' e.g. 27 December 2006 or 27 Dec 2006
'Mdy' e.g. December 27, 2006 or Dec 27, 2006 (comma is optional)
'My'  e.g. (December 2006 or Dec 2006)
'my'  e.g. 12/2006 or 12/06 (separators can be a space, period, dash, forward slash)
 if no keys are supplied, the default key that will be used is 'ymd':
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't find the parameter `MDY` in the [parameter list](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1159/date).You can try `Mdy`.

Comment: "MDY" is used in the "dateFormat" parameter for the view, but the validation looks like it wants "Mdy".

Comment: I mean  the validation ,not the form creating part.